# Disable time outside minTime and maxTime range

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I tried to link 2 jquery-ui timepicker.

```
var time = new Date();
$('#from').timepicker({
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        var startDateTextBox = $('#to');
        if (startDateTextBox.val() != '') {
            var testStartDate = new Date(startDateTextBox.val());
            var testEndDate = new Date(dateText);
            if (testStartDate > testEndDate)
                startDateTextBox.val(dateText);
        }
        else {
            startDateTextBox.val(dateText);
        }
    },
    onSelect: function(dateText){
        var time = new Date($(this).datetimepicker('getTime').getTime());
        $('#to').timepicker('option', 'minTime',time);
    }
});


$('#to').timepicker({
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        var startDateTextBox = $('#from');
        if (startDateTextBox.val() != '') {
            var testStartDate = new Date(startDateTextBox.val());
            var testEndDate = new Date(dateText);
            if (testStartDate > testEndDate)
                startDateTextBox.val(dateText);
        }
        else {
            startDateTextBox.val(dateText);
        }
    },
    onSelect: function(dateText){
        var time = new Date($(this).datetimepicker('getTime').getTime());
        $('#from').timepicker('option', 'maxTime',time);
    }
});
```

all that code do is just put timepicker value on each other input if it's empty.

I need they to look like this :

from:

[image]

to:

[image]

and when 16 is chosen in #from then all minutes above 25 will be disabled,then when 12 is chosen in #to then all minutes below 35 will be disabled.

Can it be done? if can, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read `jQuery` doc All help available there.

Here is available time picker It may be helpful

[http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/)

[http://jonthornton.github.io/Datepair.js](http://jonthornton.github.io/Datepair.js/)
https://github.com/wvega/timepicker/tree/master/test/resources/jquery-ui

Comment: hmm, i quess i have to change timepicker

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of `minTime` used here: http://timepicker.co/options/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.timepicker').timepicker({
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',
        minTime: '11:45:00' // 11:45:00 AM,
        maxHour: 20,
        maxMinutes: 30,
        startTime: new Date(0,0,0,15,0,0) // 3:00:00 PM - noon
        interval: 15 // 15 minutes
    });
});
```